# installing an plugin in eclipse it mandates me to restart the eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I am working on OSGi application. Most of the places i found the content/references that Eclipse is based on Equinox, an implementation of OSGi Release spec 4. OSGi provides one of the feature that without restarting the app you can activate the newer version of bundle ie) dynamic. But when i am installing an plugin in eclipse it mandates me to restart the eclipse to activate the plugin. As restarting is not required in OSGi technology what is the purpose of restarting in eclipse to restart? Can anybody explain the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

While OSGi fully supports dynamic update, not all code written to run on OSGi fully supports their dependencies being dynamically updated. If a bundle assumes some service it finds and uses will never go away, then that bundle will fail badly when the bundle providing the service is stopped.

So there are parts of Eclipse which are not well behaved with respect to dynamism. This is generally why the installers, e.g. p2, request you restart Eclipse after updating the set of bundles.

Answer (score 0):

An Eclipse plugin is not just OSGi code. There are also Eclipse 'extension points' (defined in the 'plugin.xml'). Eclipse may need to restart to rebuild the extension point registry.

I'm not sure but the Eclipse installer (known as 'p2') may also want to do some cleanup during the restart.